# text document sorting to sides

Tags: python, project

I'm currently learning python and I am supposed to write a program which asks a user for input of name and then input of age, It is supposed to look like this "https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5NkA.png" Sorry i cannot add pictures yet since I don't have 10 rep yet, but it looks like this for me "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrJoP.png" Please help as soon as you can, I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Also see [ask]

Comment: Among the others, consider "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague": asking for a quick response is not well considered here

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What, specifically, do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning Python, too.  I am excited because I think I can help you.

So what I would try and do is to put "Name" and "Age" on the same line and assign it to the variable "title".  What I think will also help you is if you use a variable called "space" so that you'll be able to control the formatting.  You can type in something like this:

space = " "

title = "Name" + space * 10 + "Age"

I just put the 10 in there as an estimate, but you might want to play around with the numbers to get the look you want.  After that, you can just have the program print out the title, then the inputs with formatting and I think you're all set!

I hope that steers you in the right direction.  Like I said, I am learning, too, and I haven't gotten to that part where I can call up lists yet -- but I remember it from my previous programming classes.  Please let me know if you need anything else!